# Upgrading Debian kernel on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: debian, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Debian instance in Amazon's EC2, running under HVM virtualization. I'm not sure how I originally created it; I assume from a Debian AMI.

I upgraded the underlying OS from Jessie to Stretch recently, on the instance itself, but the kernel is still running an old version, in the 3.2 family. But version 4.9 is installed; I simply cannot figure out how to select this. The instance doesn't appear to be running any version of GRUB; there's no /boot/grub and no /etc/default/grub--I don't know how it's actually booting. If it's tied to the underlying AMI, is there any way to upgrade this on the existing system?

Meanwhile, upgrading the system has rendered some applications (e.g. my MariaDB database) unusable, since it needs a more recent version of the kernel then 3.2, and I very much need the server to be functional.

What do I need to do to select the most recent kernel? I could build a new box from scratch and manually install everything into it, but I can't imagine that this is the only option for updating the kernel version.

Comment: Are you sure it's HVM? The behavior you describe is that of an ancient PV instance.

Comment: Yes, I am. At least, when I select that instance and look at the "Description" tab underneath it, it says "Virtualization: hvm".

Comment: How on earth is it booting, then? You might just want to give up and create a new instance.

Comment: I have no idea how it's booting; that's why I came here :-/

Rebuilding the entire thing will be a PITA, but if it'll give me a clean machine that works the way it's supposed to, I guess I'll have to do it.